# Mule DevKit - transformer / Cannot load application's classes

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

I am implementing a Connector with a Transformer in Mule DevKit (3.7 - Latest). I am successful in building (maven) and installing in Studio. The functionality of the Transformer is to load the class that is being passed as an argument (from payload) in runtime and access its methods to set some objects and construct a message format specific to a 3rd party protocol. When I run the application, it starts and deploys successfully; but getting Classnotfound exception. Kindly suggest/recommend a solution.

Code in my transformer class; where wsClassName is being passed as org.aa.bb.cc.MemberSearchRequestInfo (refer logs)

```
woClassObject = Class.forName(wsClassName).newInstance();
```

Mule project has the MemberSearchRequestInfo class in the specified package under src/main/java

Below is the logs.

```
2016-01-12 20:54:05,555 [[testzzmbrview1].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to transform from "java.util.HashMap" to "java.lang.String"
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
Transformer           : EnquiryMapToKkkkTransformer{this=c0fbf40, name='EnquiryMapToKkkkTransformer', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.util.HashMap, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. org.aa.bb.cc.MemberSearchRequestInfo (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
  java.net.URLClassLoader$1:-1 (null)
2. Failed to transform from "java.util.HashMap" to "java.lang.String" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.modules.xxxcore.transformers.EnquiryMapToKkkkTransformer:43 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aa.bb.cc.MemberSearchRequestInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.ddd.zz.common.KkkkRequestFormatter.applyFieldRule(KkkkRequestFormatter.java:223)
    at org.ddd.zz.common.KkkkRequestFormatter.getKkkkEnquiryRequest(KkkkRequestFormatter.java:309)
    at org.mule.modules.xxxcore.xxxcoreConnector.enquiryMapToKkkk(xxxcoreConnector.java:124)
    at org.mule.modules.xxxcore.transformers.EnquiryMapToKkkkTransformer.doTransform(EnquiryMapToKkkkTransformer.java:41)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:366)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1604)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1507)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1485)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1477)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.process(AbstractTransformer.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:303)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:293)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:193)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:471)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker$1.process(MuleInvoker.java:100)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker$1.process(MuleInvoker.java:96)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule...
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi Raj,
I think your question needs more details, the exception say he cannot found the following class org.aa.bb.cc.MemberSearchRequestInfo (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, is this class in the classpath of your application that uses the transformer ? You sure is not just a typo ?

Comment: Hi Mauro, thanks for your reply. Yes it's part of my mule project under src/main/java.

Comment: One thing I noticed now, when I add the org.aa.bb.cc.MemberSearchRequestInfo to the transformer and build it as part of the plugin, the mule application didn't throw the error. I'm not sure why the plugin is referencing its own class path and not looking for the class path in the app.

Comment: Seems like a classloading problem, you probably want to shade your library using the maven-shade-plugin. This kind of errors are common working with connectors and mule.
http://mulesoft.github.io/connector-certification-docs/advanced/index.html#_shading take a look at that link

Comment: Thanks Juan I'll try with the shade plugin.